# How to get schema attributes names from model in dynamoose v3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

In dynamoose v2:

`T extends Document;`
`model: ModelType<T>;`
`const attributes: string[] = model.schemas[0].attributes();`

In this way I get the attributes names of the schema.
How I can get attributes names from model in dynamoose v3?

In dynamoose v3:

`T extends Item;`
`model: ModelType<T>;`
`const attributes: string[] = model.schemas[0].attributes();`

I have the following error: `Property 'schemas' does not exist on type 'ModelType<T>'`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while working with Dynamoose 3. Here's a working example how to get model attributes:

```
import * as dynamoose from "dynamoose";
import {Item} from "dynamoose/dist/Item";

// Strongly typed model
class Person extends Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
const PersonModel = dynamoose.model<Person>("Person", {"id": Number, "name": String});
```

If you attempt to create a new record with an undeclared field e.g `surname`, Typescript will yell at you.

```
CatModel.create({"id": 1, "surname": "string"});
```

After creating or fetching the model, your IDE will correctly provide you the attributes.

Example 1:

```
const Person = await PersonModel.get(1);
//console.log(Person.id)
//console.log(Person.name)
```

Example 2:

```
const Person = await PersonModel.create({id: "1", name: "John" })
//console.log(Person.id)
//console.log(Person.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, because all the internal properties are only accessible by private function `#getInternalProperties` in dynamoose v3.

One of the workarounds is to export not only Model but also schema definition like this.

```js
export const UserSchema: SchemaDefinition = {
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    hashKey: true,
  },
};
export const UserModel = dynamoose.model(
  "TableName",
  [new dynamoose.Schema(UserSchema, { timestamp: true })],
  {
    // some setting for model
  },
);
```